# CCC doesn't find information about gpu

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

When I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, Catalyst Control Centre dissapeared from my computer, even though the catalyst installation manager said it was still installed.
To fix this, I uninstalled everything installed by the installation manager, and then the manager itself, and reinstalled everything. CCC now opens, but doesn't give any options for the GPU, such as Overdrive or Eyefinity. On the hardware page it shows the following:
[image: CCC]

I have an R9 280X, and all the options worked before the upgrade.

Another problem is that the GPU only outputs on HDMI now, so when I plug in a DVI monitor, it doesn't do anything.

How can I get my GPU options back in the CCC and fix it?

UPDATE:
I ran GPU-Z, and here are the results:
[image: GPU-Z]
It seems CCC didn't install the display driver correctly either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the install manager refused to properly install the display drivers, and I tried instead the Windows 7 version of the driver, and only then did it actually install. It now works fine and "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" replaced by "R9 280X" on GPU-Z. If you run into this problem too I recommend trying using a different OS - Windows 10 is not supported properly yet it appears.